# How can I lay out desired design using html and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay the header of my page out so that it looks like this:

---

[image: layout example]

---

I would like to avoid using tables if posible. I'm html and css beginer co I cannot get it working :(.

This is my best try till now:

Html:

```
<div class="rightAlign" >
    <div class="notificationArea">
        <img src="../bigHeaderImage.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="../smallImage.png" />Some info<br/>
            Other info  
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="ignoreRightAlign">
                <a href="#" >Menu1</a>
                <a href="#" >Menu2</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" >Menu3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rightAlign
{
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
}
.ignoreRightAlign
{
    float: left;
}
```

It does not work as desired of cause: Menu line is not on the bottom aligned to bottom of "Big header picture".

Thank you for any help, ideas and advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your menu to line up with the bottom of your big image though you need to absolutely position the menu items within a relative parent. I've simplified it a bit, but here are the necessary pieces to make it happen:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        .right
        {
            float: right;
        }
        .header
        {
            position: relative;
        }
        .menu
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 250px;
        }
        .info p
        {
            float: right;
        }
        .rightHeader
        {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="bigimage.png" />
        <div class="rightHeader">
            <div class="info">
                <img src="smallimage.png" /><p>Some info <br /> Other info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#" class="right">Menu 3</a>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I consider myself to be a good programer, I even give some programing lessons at university. I haven't done anything for web, mostly desktop applications or applications without GUI. Now I need to do real web site. I'm quick study I hope it will take just to learn all tags and their functions. I prefer try until I find the right solution rather then to use soem framework that will produce some horible code that I will not understand.

Comment: Fair enough, though I wouldn't consider using a framework to be a bad solution, but it wouldn't actually solve the issue you're having with the vertical alignment of your menu items. I've edited my answer to explain how to do that to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @efalconer Thank you for answer. There is one more reason for me not to use framework: This is not static html page, it is part of ASP.NET MVC web aplication. So I need to have good understanding and control ove the code so I can insert dynamic elements there they are supposed to be.

Comment: @efalconer could you please provide definition of style `.rightHeader` ? Thank you.

Comment: @drasto I've added the additional definitions you requested. Please let me know if need anything else, or would like more of an explanation of any of the elements.

Comment: @efalconer Nothing else needed. +1 and accepted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[W3 visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) is also a great read for learning how CSS layouts work.

Also:
Have you tried CSS "position"?

```
.smallPicture
{
position: absolute; //Or relative (among other options)
right: 15px; //Or whatever it needs to be
top: 0; // Can be in ##px or ##em or %
}
```

Comment: Not necessary... But its true you need to use Ids for Templates and for text and images classes, to prevent breaking the template, because you can only use an id once.

Comment: "HTML should use ids instead of classes" Uh, why?

Comment: @BoltClock : Thanks, I elaborated on that comment for clarification.

Comment: @bpeterson76 : Any suggestions as to what exactly is wrong about it?  I'd like to know if how I've been doing things is at some horrible odds to proper techniques.

Comment: Just because an item is a "template" doesn't mean it requires unique ID's to do styling.  Case in point--Jquery UI styles nearly all it's elements with classes.  Either can be used to do styling.  You are correct that ID's must be unique, and they can offer the opportunity to specifically reference an element in the DOM.  However, that's not what's being asked here, this is simple styling.  To say that you MUST use ID's for "templates" is inaccurate.

Comment: @bpeterson76 : Thanks for the clarification, I updated my answer to reflect your sentiments.

Comment: -1 I cannot see answer to my question in your post. I'm using classes where id selector would be suficient intentionaly. I understand the difference but I consider more readable for me.

Comment: @drasto I'm sorry that ids vs. classes became the focus of my answer, my intention was just to share how I approach your situation.  The W3 article and CSS "position" were intended to be the focus of the answer, and should still be helpful.

Comment: It is all right after edit. I will try what you suggest. Thank you for answer.